# Can we use "you" to refer to a general person?

Tags: questions, phrase-usage

I asked a friend of mine "Does he use workout machines that tone your ass?"

I know it's more clear if I had said "Does he use workout machines that tone his ass?", but is the first question still correct and convey the same meaning as the latter?

Comment: I know it's not part of the question, but you should also be aware that _ass_ is what used to be termed 'not in polite usage' (at least in BrE).

Answer (score 0):

As @Jim pointed out in the comments, in the exchange:

> You should try a session with my trainer, he's got a whole bunch of machines that tone pretty much every muscle you have.
>
> Oh really? *Does he use workout machines that tone your ass?*

the sentence "*Does he use workout machines that tone your ass?*" is both perfectly grammatical and sensible.

However, in that sentence, the referent of "*he*" and "*your*" are distinct; while "*your*" refers to the general "*you*" you're seeking, "*he*" is the *trainer*, not the guy with the nice ass.

The situation would be different in this exchange:

> Man, have you seen Jim's ass? It's amazing!
>
> Oh really? *Does he use workout machines that tone your ass?*

While comprehensible, the response *doesn't quite* work (at least to my ear). Rather, I'd expect you to say:

> Does he use ***those*** workout machines which tone your ass?

Which, expanded, reads "Does he use *those **type of*** workout machines which tone your ass?". Here, the referent of "he" is indeed Jim (the guy with the nice ass), and  *your* continues to work fine as a "general you": you can tell because you could easily substitute *one's* (*one* can tell because *one* could substitute *one's* :) ).

---

Note there's a subtle difference between the two sentences, now:

> Does he use ***those*** workout machines which tone your ass?

Means, does he *use a **particular type** of machine*?, whereas

> Does he use workout machines that tone his ass?

means does he *use machines in order to **achieve the particular effect** of toning his ass?*, or, more concisely, *use machines **to** tone his ass?*.

The first focuses on the *machine* he uses, the second focuses on the *effect* he gets.

Comment: I disagree that the first statement is ungrammatical.

Comment: If you elaborate, I'm happy to edit (or delete) my answer.

Comment: "You should try a session with my trainer, he's got a whole bunch of machines that tone pretty much every muscle you have."  "Oh, really?  Does he use workout machines that tone your ass?"

Comment: The first sentence is not ungrammatical. It is not Jim's responsibility to say why this is so, it is yours to say why it is not so. Which task I would not undertake.

Comment: @jim, good point, let me mull on it and edit my response

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, of course; but without elucidation of Jim's position or a specific counterexample (which he graciously provided), I'm not in a position to improve my answer, and the best we can do is downvote it as unhelpful. That's fine, so far as it goes, but it ultimately doesn't help MCHam or the next querent who comes along. In other words, it's the difference between "criticism" and "constructive criticism". In any case, given Jim's counterexample, I'm going to delete this answer as wrong (unless there are objections?).

Comment: Would you like me to downvote you? When you say 'X is ungrammatical' and it's not, I'm strongly tempted, believe me. I'll return in 30 minutes to see if you've retracted your wrong information. Your answer has some good points, but digresses from OP's query about whether it is acceptable to substitute 'your' for 'his' here.

Answer (score 0):

They are usually the same. The generalized "you" in English behaves like "on" in French, except that there is the danger of confusing it with a specific you. (As an example, if you criticize a friend by saying "That's the sort of thing you miss," it could equally mean it's the sort of thing everybody misses. But I digress) In the case of your original sentence, it is barely possible that the machines tone your friend's ass, but not that of the party you were discussing. And yes, the distinction in the second case would be that you would stress "your" to make it clear which possibility is being invoked.